# PL/SQL: My host variable doesn't print anything to the screen

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

My code:

```
create or replace procedure p9(sal in out emp_ast.salary%type) is
begin
  if sal < 3000 then
    sal := sal * 1.2;
  elsif sal between 3000 and 7000 then
    sal := sal * 1.15;
  elsif sal > 7000 then
    sal := sal * 1.1;
  elsif sal = null then
    sal := 1000;
  end if;
end p9;
/

set serveroutput on

variable g_sal number
ACCEPT g_sal number PROMPT 'Enter salary: ' 
begin
  :g_sal := &g_sal;
  p9(:g_sal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Salariu ' || :g_sal);
end;
/
```

My variable g_sal doesn't print anything to the screen . I tried giving it values like 1000 or 2000. It works with print outside the block, but the value is not changed by the function. I stays the same.

Comment: You just need to fix **null comparison**. Use `sal IS null` instead of `sal = null`

Comment: I fixed it but it's still the same.

Comment: are you really sure that you issued `set serveroutput on`

Comment: Yes. I am sure.